# tensorflow not using gpu - prime number program

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I have installed tensorflow-gpu in my laptop (GTX 1060-6GB) and I am developing a prime number generator program using tensorflow. Following is sample code i am using to calculate prime-numbers:

```
def prime_tf_graf(max_count):
    # matrix version
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        data = tf.range(2, max_count, dtype=tf.int32)
        Y, X = tf.meshgrid(data, data); Z = X%Y
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        loer = tf.matrix_band_part(Z, -1, 0) - tf.matrix_band_part(Z,  0, 0)
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        loer = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(loer, 0), tf.int32)
        sumr = tf.reduce_sum(loer, axis=1)
        nums = data - 2
        rato = tf.cast(sumr/nums, tf.int32)
        indx =  tf.cast(tf.not_equal(rato, 0), tf.int32)
    return tf.reshape(tf.where(indx), [-1]) + 2

def prime_tf(max_count):
    graf = prime_tf_graf(max_count)
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
    prim = sess.run(graf)
    return prim
```

When i run this code, my CPU and RAM get used only, and my GPU stays out of it. (only dedicated memory is allocated). Test Run: `prime_tf(tf.constant(20000))`

Here is my system usage:
[image: System usage while running tf]

It shows that tensorflow is only using my CPU and RAM not GPU.

Comment: Use a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: .how and where?